# Contract ending - Should I wait or should I speak up

Tags: negotiation, contracts, contracting

My contract as an application developer is coming to an end in a week from now.

The company has expressed that they really like me and need me and they would like to convert me to a permanent employee. At some point they also expressed they are looking for a second developer to join the team as I am the only one.

When discussing future plans with management they asked me to think and let them know what my expected salary was going to be if I went perm. After a few days I told them the figures I had in mind, which is higher than average. However the workload an skillets required to perform the job is also higher than average and rare to find a good fit and I explained that I am good fit for for the job and I provide the value that the company needs and then some, and they agreed. However, management said the figure was too high and they'll let me know what they decide as it is above their budget.

This all happened weeks ago. My contract is coming to an end in a week from now. Management said they'll 'let me know' their decision during our conversation weeks ago. I haven't heard a word since. I need to secure my position in another company if it doesn't work out with this one and a week isn't long. Moreover it seems that just recently they have been really trying hard to hire another developer.

Could this all be a  negotiation strategy? Should I ask for an update or be patient and wait for them to inform me of their decision?

I appreciate the feedback,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Ask for an update.

I've seen people send farewell emails and then have their manager rush them into a meeting room to hammer out some sort of a deal to stay. If your management is busy, they may have just forgotten when your contract expires, and the whole conversion/negotiation thing may have just fallen through the cracks.

The way to push the issue is to say: "I like this company and I like what I'm doing, but my contract is expiring in one week. Can we get together to discuss a contract extension or a conversion to full time?"

If the rate/salary that you are asking for is too high, they will either tell you or give you a counter-offer. It sounds like they need people, and they like what you've been doing. Don't be afraid of speaking up. It's the right thing to do in this situation.

Comment: "I've seen people send farewell emails and then have their manager rush them into a meeting room to hammer out some sort of a deal to stay" - I've seen people put farewell cakes on their desk and send an email round then have their manager come over and say "oooh...cakes...is it your birthday?" - "no, I'm leaving"..."<GULP!> WHAT??????????"

Comment: I'd not be surprised at all if this is the case.  Remember:  If they knew what they were doing, why would they need you?  I've also seen a manager hire a contractor back 3 days after his contract ended.  "When is Steve coming back from vacation?"  "He's not on vacation.  His contract ended."

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would arrange a one-to-one with my direct manager and explain that time is creeping by and you would appreciate an update (even if the update is "there is no update") following on from your discussions about figures some weeks back

Make it clear that you are not looking to push for a decision just that the lack of response so close to your contract end date is making you anxious and that you need to start looking at alternative offers should their decision be a negative one.

Alternatively, you could politely impose a deadline on them if you feel that your direct manager would not see this as too confrontational. I have found in the past that line managers/people who need the resource are keen to get things sorted but are tied by beaurocratic red tape either above them/or HR dept workload/incompetencies

Answer (score 1):

Simply send an e-mail to your project managers, with your manager CC'd, saying,

"Hey guys. How's it going?

Just a heads up that week X will be last week. If there is anything you would like me to transition, please let me know.

Regards, ABC"

If your manager reads this, and he is planning on renewing you, he will surely let you know right away. If not, that's that. Not all job positions are renewed.

Regarding your pay, that is something you will have to negotiate. Most managers don't know how to negotiate, so you yourself may need to continue to make lower offers until you've reached your limit. If they won't employ you for your minimum, you shouldn't work there.

Comment: Sounds like you've encountered a brilliant negotiator at some point in your past :).

Comment: Seems I have...

Comment: I think this could possibly (although not necessarily) badly backfire - it sounds like you've decided to leave and are no longer considering the role.

Comment: @JonStory This is true, to avoid this one could add to the email that they would very much like to stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you have no leverage.  Meaning - you don't have any other prospects on the table.  You should GET some, because other opportunities will become a bargaining chip.

The company has the advantage now because they know darn well that the contract is coming to an end, and you've made no efforts (as far as I can tell) to inform them that it's time to tighten their belts if they want to retain you.  I get the idea that you've approached this very casually.  A casual approach will get you casual results - which is not what I think you're looking for, at least monetarily.

Comment: You have an offer?  Then you have leverage.  I would say, "As you know, my contract is ending.  You had expressed interest in bringing me on as an employee.  Can you please let me know if that is going to happen?  I really like working with you, but I have been offered another position when this contract is complete, and I need to give them an answer, soon.  Thank you."